# qmake project exit with code -1073741511 using std ostringstream << operator

Tags: c++, c++17, qtquick2

Windows 10 64bit, mingw32, qmake, qt quick project, when I use std::ostringstream to convert something like from int to string, the project cannot be started, when I change them to std::stoi, etc, the project works.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "drawarea.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "12";
    std::cout << ss.str();
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<DrawArea>("ea.drawarea", 1, 0, "DrawArea");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

error is as below:

```
01:37:09: Starting D:\qt\build-QtquickSample-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_32_bit-Debug\debug\QtquickSample.exe ...
01:37:10: D:\qt\build-QtquickSample-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_32_bit-Debug\debug\QtquickSample.exe exited with code -1073741511
```

If comment out below code, it will work.

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << "12";
std::cout << ss.str();
```

Why is this?

Just find that when I use filesystem::path (mingw things) in the code, also exit with that error code.

Note: I use c++17, with quick and quickocntrols2.

============================================================
update 2022.8.18

When I create a console project using cmake, the project works

```
# Set the minimum version of CMake that can be used
# To find the cmake version run
# $ cmake --version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

# Set the project name
project (hello_cmake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# Add an executable
add_executable(hello_cmake main.cpp)
```

the c++ code is as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "12";
    std::cout << ss.str();

   std::cout << "Hello CMake!" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: HRESULT decoder for [-1073741511](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=-1073741511) can be helpful.

Comment: In general, when you get a crazy number, convert it to hex and see if it's more recognizable.

Comment: If you comment out everything but the `ostringstream` usage, so you get [this](https://godbolt.org/z/xdnGvsYdT), does it still behave strangely?

Comment: That error code likely means you have a dll conflict. Maybe you have multiple versions of MinGW installed and their folders are your PATH environment variable causing the wrong one to be listed in the `PATH` first.

Comment: I check the code, it means "STATUS_ENTRYPOINT_NOT_FOUND", why does it affect the entry point?

Comment: @drescherjm, that could the root cause, I install a mingw32 in C:\msys64\mingw32, and another is with Qt installation in C:\Qt\5.15.2\mingw81_32, how to solve the issue, can I just uninstall the one with Qt installation directory?

Comment: Temporarily you can switch the order in your PATH environment variable in your OS settings.

Comment: @drescherjm, there are two folders: C:\msys64\mingw32\bin and C:\Qt\5.15.2\mingw81_32\bin, when I copy libstdc++-6.dll from the first folder to the second folder, the ostringstream works, only switch the order not work. I want to uninstall the mingw81_32, but the qmake.exe is in that folder, I have no idea how to do for next.